# CircleCI - Scheduled workflow does not run Cypress

Tags: continuous-integration, cypress, pipeline, circleci

The below code works fine whenever there is a new commit. It automatically runs which is fine.
However, I want to schedule a workflow that should run daily on a specific time. But the below
code is not working for that. Any idea what could be wrong here?

```
version: 2.1
orbs:
  cypress: cypress-io/cypress@1
workflows:
  build:
    jobs:
      - cypress/run:
          store_artifacts: true
scheduled-workflow:
  triggers:
    - schedule:
        corn: "30 20 * * 1,2,3,4,5,6"
        filters:
          branches:
            only: master
  jobs:
    - cypress/run
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I read: `corn: "30 20 * * 1,2,3,4,5,6"`. `corn` is yummy but it's not great for scheduling tasks; try `cron` :D

If it still doesn't work, try with a slightly modified syntax for your `filters` section:

```
scheduled-workflow:
  triggers:
    - schedule:
        cron: "30 20 * * 1,2,3,4,5,6"
        filters:
          branches:
            only:
              - master
```

Let me know if this helps.

Comment: That being said, as the `corn` (instead of `cron`) typo passes the config validation, you couldn't get any hint on what was causing the issue. It'd be something to bring up to CircleCI's attention. Although, since the [scheduled workflows functionality will be phased out by the end of 2022](https://circleci.com/docs/workflows/#scheduling-a-workflow), I'd highly recommend migrating to [scheduled pipeline](https://circleci.com/docs/scheduled-pipelines/).

Comment: Ah Thanks, Will surely look into scheduled pipelines. Thanks for the help though.